# How do I change a color of an event in extensible calendar?

Tags: extjs, extensible

By digging through some example code I figured out that an **event** has a number of properties such as **id**, **title**, **start**, **end** :

```
    "evts" : [{
        "id"    : 1001,
        "cid"   : 1,
        "title" : "TRACPaket1",
        "start" : makeDate(-20, 10), //d, //h
        "end"   : makeDate(10, 15),
        "notes" : "Have fun"
    },..
```

I would like to see what other things I can do with an event. For instance, it would be good if I could change the background (or foreground) color of an event, or even add a custom icon to the event.

Is this documented anywhere? Is there a complete list of what constitutes an event object?

Answer (score 1):

Might [these docs](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Extensible.calendar.data.EventMappings) be what you were looking for?  After a quick scan of the page, I couldn't find anything pertaining to colors within the events themselves, but I imagine it's possible.

Comment: In hindsight, this should have been a comment, rather than a fully-fledged answer, since it apparently doesn't address the entirety of your question.

Comment: yeah i had a look at that custom-mappings but it confused me even more. My data has 'start', but that mapping has 'StartDate', 'StartDt', and 'start_dt'. I'm not sure what is what.

Comment: @OliverWatkins did you check out the [source](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/EventMappings.html#cls-Extensible.calendar.data.EventMappings) too?  There's an entry in there which appears to associate the `name` "StartDate" to `mapping` "start" (towards the bottom).  It also contains all that `start_dt` stuff.

Comment: thanks, I have absolutely no clue how to use this calendar because there is no documetnation (except a little in the API docs). We are probably going to dump this component and go with something else.

Comment: @OliverWatkins no problemo boss. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!